# Performance issue while iterating through repo's commits?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I want to display just the first 100 commits of a repository. I used the linux-repo to test this:

```
        const int maxSize = 100;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine( "Getting Commits in own Thread" );
        sw.Start();

        using( Repository repo = new Repository( path_to_linux_repo ) )
        {
            ICommitLog commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy( new CommitFilter { Since = "HEAD" } );

            int index = 0;
            foreach( Commit commit in commits )
            {
                if( index++ > maxSize ) break;                    
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine( "Took {0}ms for {1} entries", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, maxSize );
```

This simple loop takes over 9000ms on my machine. Its FAR faster when using a repo with less commits, but why is it so slow in repos with a lot of commits?
Another question: is it possible to just retrieve a given number of commits e.g. to page through
all commits?

Comment: It definitely shouldn't take that long to look at 100 commits. Is it still as slow if you use a `CommitFilter` with `SortBy = CommitSortStrategies.None`?

Comment: Makes no difference. Took 9000ms too. Even without any CommitFilter at all.

Comment: Not passing a filter means using a time sorting. It's not the same as passing a sorting of none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce here. It's definitely far too long to take. It looks as though libgit2 is enqueueing the full graph before returning, which would be a bug with the given settings. Would you mind opening an issue?

As for retrieving a number of commits, the iteration is pull-based, so you will only grab as many out of the repository as you ask for. the commit log implements `IEnumerable` so you can use whatever LINQ methods you like (or do it manually as in this example).

---

**UPDATE:**

The bug was quite embarrassing, but there's a **[PR to fix it](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2195)** in libgit2 which will make its way into libgit2sharp releases in due course. With the fix, this test now takes ~80ms. Thanks for bringing it up.

**UPDATE 2:**

The fix is now available in the `vNext` branch of LibGit2Sharp.